# Запуск tomcat из под IDEA на доменном имени

Tags: intellij-idea, java-ee, tomcat, развертывание

Подскажите пожалуйста. Запускаю проект из IDEA. 
Как мне сделать что бы мой проект открывался по ссылке, к примеру `myproject.dev`, вместо `localhost:8080`?
Пробовал в настройки tomcat в IDEA прописывать так, но ничего не работает. 
Правил файл `hosts` и ставил так  `127.0.0.1 myproject.dev`, но тоже ничего не работает.

Что я делаю не так?